# Scroll function scrolling infinitely; makes footer inaccessible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I am trying to implement a sidebar to follow the user's screen as he or she scrolls up or down in the browser page. However I am getting an issue where the sidebar continues to scroll down the page infinitely if the user keeps scrolling down.

```
 var element = $('#movingBox'),
    originalY = element.offset().top;

// Space between element and top of screen (when scrolling)
var topMargin = 100;



$(window).on('scroll', function(event) {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    element.stop(false, false).animate({
        top: scrollTop < originalY
                ? 0
                : scrollTop - originalY + topMargin
    }, 300);
});
```

Is there a way to limit the sidebar from scrolling too far down than its supposed to?

Comment: Can u show a demo please?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I have understood your question. You want to stop the box following at a certain position like this ?

```
var element = $('#movingBox'),
    originalY = element.offset().top;

// Space between element and top of screen (when scrolling)
var topMargin = 100;

$(window).on('scroll', function(event) {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    var stop = $('#stop').offset().top; // or in pixel
    stop -= $('#movingBox').height() + topMargin;

    if (scrollTop<stop) {
        element.stop(false, false).animate({
            top: scrollTop < originalY
                    ? 0
                    : scrollTop - originalY + topMargin
        }, 300);
    }
});
```

[Try the example in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dfbf1amo/)